# onclick function are not working?

Tags: php, jquery

code:

```
<input type="text" name="college_name" id="college_name" placeholder="Search By College Name" >
<div id="box"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#college_name").keyup(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "colleges.php",
                data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#box").show();
                    $("#box").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function selectCollege(val) {
        $("#college_name").val(val);
        college_name = $("#college_name").val();
        location.href = "college-details.php?college_name=" + college_name;
        $("#box").hide();
    }
</script>
```

college.php

```
<?php
   $tempcollege .= "<a href='#' style='color:#fff;'><li onClick=selectCollege('".$college_name."''".$field."');>".$college_name.$field."</li></a>";
?>
```

In this code I have created a autocomplete box where all colleges are displaying when I keyup on input field but when click on any college then it not go to link i.e. college-details.php. So, How can I fix this problem ?please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Check the console for the error. Your not setting the quotes properly in the HTML you're generating in the PHP code. Also note that I'd suggest you use a delegated click event handler instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes

Comment: Why do you have an `li` element inside an `a` element if you want to use `onClick` ?

Comment: I think the `data` argument in the ajax function should use a colon rather than an equals sign. ie: `data:$(this).val()`

Comment: The question has nothing to do with perl mysqli Interface. That's why i removed the tag

Comment: i would suggest you to give an `id` to anchor tag and use `$("#id").click(function(){//code goes here});` to handle click event from external JavaScript file or inside script tag.

Comment: @ArunSivan  multiple same id will not work with jQuery.

Comment: Don't diagnose JavaScript code by looking at the server-side template that will eventually generate it. Look directly at the actual code that's running!

Comment: This question is about JavaScript but there is no tag for it. Do you expect a jQuery solution?

Comment: try onClick() to onclick()

Comment: That's correct @AlivetoDie. In case of dynamic html content this is not possible but you can use `class` and then later refer the properties using `$(this)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be multiple issues in your college.php:

1. normally <li> should be outside <a>,
2. href equals to "#", which in some cases causes browser to load/reload a page and since click event is also bubbled to <a>,

You can avoid this two ways.

Either replace href='#' with href='javascript:void(0)'

```
<?php
    $tempcollege .= "<li onClick=selectCollege('".$college_name."''".$field."');><a href='javascript:void(0)' style='color:#fff;'>".$college_name.$field."</a></li>";
?>
```

or cancel event bubbling and executing default behaviour of <a> tag in onClick by returning false.

```
<?php
    $tempcollege .= "<li onClick=\"selectCollege('".$college_name."''".$field."'); return false;\"><a href='#' style='color:#fff;'>".$college_name.$field."</a></li>";
?>
```

Worst case scenaro if you cannot edit the college.php, then add `window.event.preventDefault();` to selectCollege() function:

```
function selectCollege(val) {
    window.event.preventDefault();
    $("#college_name").val(val);
    college_name = $("#college_name").val();
    location.href = "college-details.php?college_name=" + college_name;
    $("#box").hide();
}
```

There is also another error: `selectCollege('".$college_name."''".$field."');` generates code `selectCollege('Some college name''Some field');`, which contains two apostrophes going in a row. It seems you wanted `selectCollege('Some college nameSome field');`, so really you should also fix the code to `selectCollege('".$college_name.$field."');` or `selectCollege('".$college_name."'+'".$field."');`

Comment: Thanx @viacheslav

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<?php
$tempcollege .= "<a href='#' style='color:#fff;'><li onClick=selectCollege('".$college_name."''".$field."');>".$college_name.$field."</li></a>";
?>
```

With

```
<?php
$tempcollege .= "<a href='#' style='color:#fff;'><li onclick=selectCollege('".$college_name."''".$field."');>".$college_name.$field."</li></a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $tempcollege .= "<li><a onclick='callfunction();' style='color:#fff;'>click</a></li>";       
    When you set click event on <a> tag at time please remove href="#" attribute with href some cases causes browser reload a page and since click event  not work.
```

Comment: Put some explanation.